# Update Patch Microsoft Graph API Planner Task Detail using JSON cURL through FileMaker Pro produces error 204

Tags: json, curl, filemaker, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

After successfully creating a new Planner Task, I retrieve the Planner Task Detail ID and am trying to update the Task Detail.  When doing so, I receive an error 204 "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content"

I am trying to do this using FileMaker and their INSERT FROM URL command.

the URL is:
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/" & $microsoftplannerTaskDetailID & "/details"

the cURL Options which I set in a variable is:
"-X PATCH " &
" -H "Authorization: Bearer " & $$userToken & """ &
" -H "Content-Type: application/json"" &
" -H "If-Match: W/\"JzEtFza0RlFpbHMgQBAQBAQEBARCc=\""" &
" -d @$PlannerTaskDetails" &
" -D $responseHeaders" & //returns error codes
" Prefer: return=representation" // if successful, returns the full header that you sent

which resolves as:

-X PATCH  -H "Authorization: Bearer J0eXAiOiJ<>NTb2VEdDJsbVJXa3FEeVcwVUkiLCJINYoz8P7NxmOcbA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "If-Match: W/"JzEtVGFza0RQEBARCc="" -d @$PlannerTaskDetails -D $responseHeaders Prefer: return=representation

the $PlannerTaskDetails variable is set as:
"{" & ""previewType": "noPreview"," & ""description": "This is a test"" & "}"

which resolves as: {"previewType": "noPreview","description": "This is a test"}

I was previously having an error related to the If-Match being incorrect, but think I have resolved that.  But just in case that is causing an issue still, I wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that http status codes starting with 2 represent a SUCCESSFUL call.

204 means Success, but there is nothing to return.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

As such it is NOT an error